# List Manager Owner Field

Tags: segmented-list

I am using Sitecore 10.2, when creating contact list I found the owner field drop down is not populated.

I want to know how I can populate it and does it have affect on the security access of the list?

Any advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the same issue already in Sitecore 10.1.

To answer your questions:

- The fact that `owner` field is empty does NOT have impact on security. The `owner` field of contact list is not related in any way to access rights.
- `Owner` field is used when displaying `My Lists` in List Manager - Sitecore will show all the lists created by given user or which have `Owner` field equal to current user name (including `sitecore\` domain, e.g. `sitecore\marekmusielak`).
- `Owner` field can be populated manually in Content Editor - find your contact list item under `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Contact Lists/` and fill `Owner` field in `Data` section:
  [image: Sitecore Contact List Owner]